# npm install --save loopback-connector failed to install

Tags: node.js, database

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install --save loopback-connector
```

> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program
>   Files\nod ejs\package.json' C:\Program Files\nodejs
>   -- loopback-connector@2.4.0   +-- async@1.5.2   -- debug@2.2.0
>       -- ms@0.7.1
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs \package.json' npm WARN nodejs No description npm WARN
>   nodejs No repository field. npm WARN nodejs No README data npm WARN
>   nodejs No license field.

Comment: I'm not at home at the moment to check, but it sounds like you are trying to use `--save` but npm can't find a package.json file in the folder you are currently in.  Use `-g` instead of `--save` to install it globally or use `--save` to save this to your package.json file when you are in an actual project folder where that file will exist

Comment: You should look at the [npm install docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/node.js/482/npm/1588/installing-packages#t=201608052018465617743), that should help you understand how to use `npm install` and the [npm init docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/node.js/482/npm/2257/setting-up-a-package-configuration#t=20160805201949661253) for how to initialize your `package.json` for your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `loopback-connector` to be available via the command line and globally to all project (this is sometimes the case, such as with utilities such as the `grunt-cli`), install globally:

`~ npm install -g loopback-connector`

However, if you want it installed in a project folder, make sure you have initialized your node project. In example below, my project is called `myProject`:

`~ mkdir myProject`

`~ cd myProject`

`~ npm init`

go through the wizard. This will set up a file called `package.json`

Install `loopback-connector`:

`~ npm install loopback-connector --save`